# Does all browsers support .svg image format

Tags: image-processing

is .svg a replacement for .jpeg or others?
Can we secure images with .svg format.? And what browsers are currently have suport for .svg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SVG is supported by all major browsers but IE8 and later versions need a plugin to display the image and its free.

Their vector based structure allows to display them on many different devices with various screen sizes without losing visual information. And is more compressible than JPEG and GIF images

Answer (score 1):

There is a wealth of information about Scalable Vector Graphics on the 'Net.

It provides alternatives to static images and animations.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics) has a definition and [a breakdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_browsers) by browser.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly Android (mobile Chrome) and WP7 devices do not support SVG format. Android developers blames it on "saving space". :(